# Is it possible to work with git in UMLdesigner?

Tags: git, uml-designer

I am working on the standalone version of UMLdesigner.

Is there a way to work with GIT in UMLdesigner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF [UML Designer](http://www.umldesigner.org/) saving files are text-based, then you can version those models.

You can see an example of such a git repo for an UML Designer project in [issue 877](https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/UML-Designer/issues/877).
The `*.uml` files are xml text files.

But there is no direct integration that I can see in the [`ObeoNetwork/UML-Designer`](https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/UML-Designer) project itself which would make versioning operation directly visible from the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

As UML Designer is based on Eclipse, you can use EGit to get a GUI to work with Git in UML Designer: https://www.eclipse.org/egit/

To install it, you can use the foloowing update site URLs, copy and paste it into the “Help > Install new software” dialog: http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates

Answer (score 1):

Since June the EMF compare project ships an integration plugin which should allow UML Designer to provide basic functionnalities regarding compare & merging.

Things similar to [how EcoreTools behave with this integration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M99mw.png)

I just tracked [an issue on github](https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/UML-Designer/issues/889) if you want